# Formatting scala template files in IntelliJ

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework-2.0

I am using Intellij to create a Play2 project. I have installed the Play2 support and Scala plugins. But when I try to format index.scala.html using IDE all the JavaScript code in the template get messed up (indentation). I renamed the file to index.html and try to format it. Then it get properly formatted. How to fix this problem?

Comment: what do you mean by `messed up`?

Comment: All the indentation are gone in java script code.

Comment: I created a issue for this http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-7372

Comment: @elyse left aside the fact that writing js in an html file is not the proper way to define html behavior, it is a way to do it. IntelliJ's scala and play plugins should support it for it is supported by it's html and js plugins.

Comment: Do you have IntelliJ CE or Ultimate? I'm wondering if you have the full JetBrains "twirl" file editor.